# How to put data from jquery each into object variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several select tags with different values of name attribute. I must get each of the value and put it into object variable. How to do it?
My code:

```js
var obj = {};

$('.variants tbody tr td.value').children('select').each(function(index, value) {
  alert($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="variants">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="value">
        <select name="color">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="value">
        <select name="size">
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="value">
        <select name="material">
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, I must get

```
{"color":"selected_option_value", "size":"selected_option_value", "material":"selected_option_value"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select all `select` elements in the table (you don’t need such a complex jQuery query to achieve so), iterate thru the collection; then for each element of the collection get its name (using the `attr()` function) and selected value (using the `val()` function) and create a property on the output object (`obj`) using the name of the `select` and assign its value to the `select` value.

```
// define the container object
var obj = {};

// for each select in the table
$('.variants select').each(function(index, select) {

    // set the current item as a jQuery object
    var current = $(select);

    // sets the object key using the name of the select and the current selected value as the object key value
    obj[current.attr('name')] = current.val();

});

// output
console.log(obj);
```

You could do the same using vanilla JavaScript too as in the other answers examples.

Comment: @Ivan hope my edit fits your explanation expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the selection inputs with a `forEach` loop and fill in the `obj` object:

1. Select the input boxes and unwrap them in an array:

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('.value')]
   ```
2. in the loop select the child `select` element with:

   ```
   menu.querySelector('select')
   ```
3. then add a new key/value pair in `obj`:

   ```
   obj[element.getAttribute('name')] = element.value
                   ↑                         ↑
                  key                      value
   ```

So the full code looks like:

```
const obj = {}

document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  [...document.querySelectorAll('.value')].forEach(menu => {

    const element = menu.querySelector('select');

    obj[element.getAttribute('name')] = element.value

  })

  console.log(obj)

})
```

I have set an event listener to show it working:

```js
const obj = {}

document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  [...document.querySelectorAll('.value')].forEach(menu => {

    const element = menu.querySelector('select');

    obj[element.getAttribute('name')] = element.value

  })

  console.log(obj)

})
```

```html
<table class="variants">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="value">
        <select name="color">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="value">
        <select name="size">
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="value">
        <select name="material">
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button class="button">Give object</button>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you downvoted? Any suggestions to improve my answer?

Comment: Didn’t downvoted your answer but maybe because you will need a transpiler like Babel to make this work in some browser. Maybe es5 vanilla js will be the right choice for the one who downvoted. Got a downvote in some other question just to add to the "how to on es6" so... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery to do this you, this will return an object on page load. You will have to wrap this in a function and add an event listener to return an object when the select values have changed or on form submission if thats what you are trying to accomplish

```
const variantsTable = document.querySelector('.variants')
const variantsSelects = Array.from(variantsTable.querySelectorAll('select'))

const obj = {}

variantsSelects.forEach(item => {
    obj[item.name] = item.value
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

Output :

```
{"color":"1","size":"4","material":"7"}
```

You can try here :

```js
const obj = {};

$('table.variants td.value select').each(function(index) {
  obj[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
});

$("#output").text(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="variants">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td class="value">
        <select name="color">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td class="value">
        <select name="size">
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td class="value">
        <select name="material">
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```